# docker-compose build failed - Release file for http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease is expired

Tags: ruby, linux, docker, ubuntu, debian

I am new for docker and I've struggled with this problem for a couple of hours. When running docker-compose build.

I tried several ways that from stackoverflow or other articles. However, they don't work for me.

This is the things I've tried

① Add `RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list` before `RUN apt-get -y update`

② Add `RUN sed -i '/jessie-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list  # Now archived` before `RUN apt-get -y update`

③ Add `echo 'Acquire::Check-Valid-Until no;' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99no-check-valid-until` before `RUN apt-get -y update`

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.2.8

RUN apt-get -y update

RUN apt-get -y install libssl-dev libreadline6-dev libyaml-dev autoconf links rsync bc zip
RUN apt-get -y install memcached curl nodejs npm mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev git vim libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev openssl libcurl4-openssl-dev libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev imagemagick

            ...
```

```
Step 1/21 : FROM ruby:2.2.8
2.2.8: Pulling from library/ruby
f49cf87b52c1: Pull complete
7b491c575b06: Pull complete
b313b08bab3b: Pull complete
51d6678c3f0e: Pull complete
b7e583189d20: Pull complete
46dce29fd829: Pull complete
8c6977c77c0a: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:d9040e79905220faccc1bfa7ecba473ed81d00806e37e153edb52131aef8cdc6
Status: Downloaded newer image for ruby:2.2.8
 ---> 17a7476794ed
Step 2/21 : RUN apt-get -y update
 ---> Running in d6d37a14768f
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [16.3 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [1652 B]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release [77.3 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [20 B]
E: Release file for http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease is expired (invalid since 234d 11h 20min 27s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
ERROR: Service 'rails-app' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Could somebody help me out to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Try to change `RUN apt-get -y update` to `RUN apt-get -y -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update` and retry

Comment: I tried it. However, it didn't work well.  `W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch`